# Git bash doesn't save repository path

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm using git bash and I have one problem.

When I open the git bash and I write "pwd" I get the current path of git.
I get something like this:

> c:/users/bla

Every time I have to change the path with "cd" command.
Why doesn't git save my repository path like it saves my username and email?

Answer (score 1):

The current working directory is a property of bash, not something normally saved in git.

If you want to start in a particular path, then just add the appropriate `cd` command to the file `~/.bashrc`. You can do this with the following command inside `git-bash`.

```
echo 'cd what/ever/you/want' >> ~/.bashrc
```